# How can I execute an Excel function?

Tags: function, excel, worksheet-function, vba

Is there a way to wrap calls to Excel built-in functions in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, just prefix with `WorksheetFunction`.

eg `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...`

Comment: Nice, thanks ! However, it seems like not all of the functions are there. For example, what about the TODAY() Excel function ? Or is this one part of some particular set of functions ?

Comment: I think only the functions that don't have native VBA equivalents are available. For example VBA already has `Date` as a function to get Today.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that there are two ways to use (eg) VLOOKUP in VBA: `someVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(...)` and `someVar = Application.Vlookup(...)` The first will throw an error if the lookup value is not found, but the second will not, instead returning an error value in 'someVar' which you can test with IsError()